# Append two videos without duplicating FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, h.264, video-capture, mkv

Let's say we have 2 video files (X,Y) in the same format, codec and dimensions.

X is a longer video with several gigabytes in size. Y is a short 10 second video. I want to append Y to the end of X without creating another copy of X (Because it's **big** in size)

I have to repeat this process for hours with many 10 second videos arriving one after another.

**Currently,** I'm concatenating files using ffmpeg.

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i chunk.list -c copy final-video.mkv`

`chunk.list` contains file names of X and several 10 second videos. After this, X will be deleted and replaced by `final-video.mkv`. Then, repeat.

##### But this needs twice the storage capacity and I/O operations. How to do this without creating duplicates?

It's okay to duplicate these 10 second videos. But duplicating that bigger file `X` really hurts performance.

###### Additional info :

All these videos will be encoded with H264, H265, VP8 or VP9 and contained in MKV or MP4 as they are `codec copy friendly`. **Only one** of these formats will be used.

This is for a special case screen recorder that's supposed to run on cloud and preemptive remote desktops (Linux).
HTML/JS browser front-end captures the screen and sends to the back-end (Golang) as chunks through HTTP. Network route is undefined and unreliable as there can be firewalls/proxies between the front-end and the back-end. Therefore, we can't use connections like UDP. So the only option is to send video chunks using HTTP.

It's FOSS on https://github.com/HasinduLanka/screencorder

Comment: a) ffmpeg does not edit files in-place, b) even if it did, MP4s and MKVs aren't edit-friendly. You will need space for a temporary file.

Comment: Is there a "append friendly" video format?

Comment: MPEG-TS, but you'll still need a tempfile.